# Pluralization of Germanisms

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, germanic-languages, i-mutation

The German noun "Ansatz" is widely used (at least) in physics and, less frequently, in math texts in English. I have seen it always in singular though and now I must use its (English) plural. The German plural of this word is "Ansätze".

Which of the following plural forms is the right one for the Germanism "Ansatz"?

1. Ansatzs (perhaps the expected one)
2. Ansätze (too exaggerated?)
3. other unexpected, like "these Ansatz are..." (unchanged)

Comment: By the way, I have often wondered what the best translation would be. "Educated guess" comes to mind but I'm sure one can do better. Suggestions anybody?

Comment: Yes, "educated guess" sounds good.  "Judicious guess" is a common name for a method in differential equations which, I think, tacitly tries to replace "ansatz".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [OED entry for *ansatz*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/240569) lists it as a regular noun in English.  That means it takes *-es* for the plural here.

On the other hand, its earliest citation almost looks invariant:

- 1942    *Jrnl. Indian Math.* Soc. 6 41 (title)    Studies in Fourier ansatz and
  parabolic equations.

The other citations, through 1990, all look completely singular. There are no clear examples of a plural. It just isn’t marked as irregular, and they always do that if it is.

There are ***extremely*** few words in the OED of German derivation that retain their German plural in English, perhaps a half-dozen odd ones, and seldom as the dominant form.  For example, there is one citation from 1962 of *bratwurst* > *bratwürste*:

- 1962   *Punch* 11 July 51/2   We ate two delicious Bratwürste apiece.

In contrast, *Wandervogel* is definitely marked *Wandervögel* in the plural, and the plural forms *Wandervogel* and *Wandervogeln* are marked catachrestic — that is, erroneous.  Here are two examples of the word as an irregular plural:

- 1967   *Listener* 30 Nov. 705/3   Around 1930, alienated and disaffected youth was being manufactured mainly in Germany, where the First War had produced the biggest earthquake. Some of them called themselves the *Wandervögel*, and wandered around Europe with their guitars and their interchangeable girlfriends, living on what they could get wherever sympathisers would accept them.
- 1978   J. I. M. Stewart *Full Term* xxi. 241   A bunch of juvenile *Wandervögel*.

You can tell those uses aren’t assimilated because they’re still written in italic in the original.  And they’re still capitalized, unlike most (but not all) citations of *ansatz*.

One more example with an irregular German plural in English is *Land*, “a semi-autonomous unit of local government in Germany and Austria”, whose plural is given as any of  *Länder*  `/ˈlɛndər/`, *Laender*, *Lands*, and in that order.

Comment: you mean, with respect to the word "ansatz" in the paper of Minakshisundaram, is "ansatz" in plural in the text not just in the title?

Comment: @JorgeCampos The OED citation is just for the title, not the contents, and I haven’t myself read Minakshisundaram’s doctoral thesis to see how he uses it therein.

Comment: Thanks again. Well, in that case he is using ansatz in singular in that title- so it is not invariant because it is singular. Otherwise very illuminating!

Answer (score 5):

The most commonly used plural in English  seems to be "ansätze".

Searching in Google books between 1990 and 2010, I find [98 results](http://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=%22the+ansatzes%22&tbs=,cdr:1,cd_min%3aJan+1_2+1990,cd_max%3aDec+31_2+2010&num=10#q=%22the+ansatze%22&hl=en&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min%3aJan+1_2+1990,cd_max%3aDec+31_2+2010,lr%3alang_1en&tbm=bks&psj=1&ei=fmzVT6q4E8rD6gGt_rG7Aw&start=90&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=2021d98a66ba8649&biw=936&bih=499) for "the ansatze" and [only 36](http://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=%22the+ansatzes%22&tbs=,cdr:1,cd_min%3aJan+1_2+1990,cd_max%3aDec+31_2+2010&num=10#q=%22the+ansatzes%22&hl=en&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min%3aJan+1_2+1990,cd_max%3aDec+31_2+2010,lr%3alang_1en&tbm=bks&psj=1&ei=DWzVT6C8IIfB6AHliMCsAw&start=30&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=2021d98a66ba8649&biw=936&bih=499) for "the ansatzes". (I added "the" to eliminate German results, which dominate if you leave it out, even if you ask for English pages).

Google web search returns [372 results](http://www.google.com/#q=%22the+ansatze%22&hl=en&prmd=imvns&psj=1&ei=x3DVT8anBMmF6QH_qficAw&start=369&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=4e154b18253a8ec1&biw=936&bih=499) for "the ansatze" and [283 results](http://www.google.com/#q=%22the+ansatzes%22&hl=en&prmd=imvnsb&psj=1&ei=SXDVT-uIJqKe6QHTpvj9Ag&start=275&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=4e154b18253a8ec1&biw=936&bih=499) for "the ansatzes".

Looking at the actual results, the majority of them seem to have umlauts (you often have to click the link and look at the document itself to check for an umlaut) and are lower-case, so despite what the dictionaries say, I would recommend using *ansätze* as the plural.

Comment: Although note *ansatzes* is a perfectly good plural as well, and both *ansaetze* and *ansatze* (without the umlaut) appear.

Comment: ...and I do prefer it with _umlaut_!

Answer (score 4):

"Ansatzes" is most commonly used as a plural in English.

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ansatz

Comment: oh, it was in Wiktionary...I should have seen there first. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. It was an interesting question :)

Comment: ...but with or without capital?

Comment: In English text, without capital.

Comment: And why do you believe Wiktionary?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an indirect argument for *Ansätze*.
The core result of classical algebraic geometry is Hilbert's zeros theorem.
In all languages I am aware of it is usually referred to as *Nullstellensatz*, with a footnote translating it into the language of the text.
Since there are various more or less general versions of this result one is led to speak of *Nullstellensätze* or some other plural forms.
Google gives 2590 answers for  *Nullstellensätze* and only 142 for *Nullstellensatzs*.
[Here](http://www.google.com/search?q=nullstellens%C3%A4tze&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3afr%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) is the first page of the answers for *Nullstellensätze*.

On a personal note it has happened a few times that I told mathematicians who had written, say, *Nullstellensatzs* that the German plural was *Nullstellensätze*.
What is interesting is that, although I absolutely did not plead for the German plural but just gave them the information , they immediately modified  their original text and  adopted that German form.

Comment: The correctly formed English plural is not Nullstellensatzs but Nullstellensatzes, although the German one is probably used more often (definitely by mathematicians; on arxiv.org the German plural wins 27 to 2, with Nullstellensatze—no umlaut—coming in second with around 9 hits).

Comment: Just Google search probably doesn't work. If you search for "Nullstellensatzes", you get 4330 results, but most of these are in German, where *Nullstellensatzes* is the genitive case. This makes me suspect that many of the results for *Nullstellensätze* are also in German, although the English ones seem to appear first.